# Branch.io (Android SDK): what should I set in <data android:scheme="androidexample" />?

Tags: java, android, branch.io, fabric.io, attribution

I am trying to implement Branch.io in my project.

According to the doc: https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/

I need to replace "androidexample" in :

```
<!-- Branch URI Scheme -->
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="androidexample" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
```

by the value in my dashboard. I don't see where to find this value in my dashboard.

May you explain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackie from Branch here.

Please replace "androidexample" with your own Android scheme. This value should match whatever you provide on the dashboard link setting page:

[image]

Best,

Comment: Another question : should I replace "androidexample" by "myapp" or "myapp://" ?

Comment: Please replace those values with your own from Branch account dashboard. myapp:// is only a placeholder.